# How do I stream a dynamically generated CSV file to the browser for download in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I need to allow a user to download a large dynamically generated CSV file (~500K lines) from a browser (Java/Spring MVC 4.x app) I don't want to have to create the entire file first and have the browser long-poll the server to determine when it is complete -- rather, I want to start the download immediately and have the server stream the response as the new lines/bytes become available.

I've tried using ServletOutputStream/PrintWriter to add the text as it becomes available and then flush the buffer. However, the browser doesn't appear to start downloading until the controller method returns. (after flushBuffer() is called, you'll see the file appear as a download with the message "starting" in Chrome).

Is there a better way to do this? I see StreamingResponseBody was introduced in Spring 4.2, but I'd rather not upgrade if possible. Is there a way to do this with Spring <4.2?

Answer (score 0):

using ServletOutputStream/PrintWriter to add the text as it becomes available and then flush the buffer in fact seems to work... Chrome will show "starting download" for a while and then slowy show the size of the download increase as expected.